Troubleshooting 404 Error in QR Code Generation for Android Management API Enrollment Token
I have developed a Mobile Device Management application using the Google Android Management API in Node.js. The application was working properly, but now I am facing a 404 not found error when I create an enrollment token with the QR code. Can you suggest a solution to resolve this issue?
here is the code
const createEnrollmentToken = async (req,res,policyId) => {
    try {
        if (global.collectionExists) {
            console.log(`Collection already exists. Data will not be stored.`);
        } else {
            
            // Qr Code Exapraition time setting for 1000 years
            const durationInYears = 1000;
            const secondsInYear = 365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60; // 365.25 days in a year to account for leap years
            const durationInSeconds = durationInYears * secondsInYear;
            const enrollmentToken = await androidManagementClient.enterprises.enrollmentTokens.create({
                parent: global.enterpriseName,
                requestBody: {
                    policyName: policyId,
                    duration: `${durationInSeconds}s`,
                }
            });
            console.log('Enrollment token created successfully:', enrollmentToken.data);
            try {
                /* qr image  */
                const policies = await PoliciesDataModel.find({ username: global.adminUserName, "Polices.policyName": req.body.policyId });
                if (policies && policies.length > 0) {
                    const image = {
                        'cht': 'qr',                                      //cht represents the type of the chart or image, and its value is set to 'qr'.
                        'chs': '320x320',                                //chs specifies the size of the chart or image, and its value is set to '500x500', indicating a width and height of 500 pixels each.
                        'chl': enrollmentToken.data.qrCode               //chl is the URL or data for the chart or image, and its value is taken from enrollmentToken.data.qrCode.
                    };
                    console.log(enrollmentToken.data.qrCode  )
                    const qrcodeImgUrl = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?' + querystring.stringify(image);
                    console.log('qrcodeImgUrl : ', qrcodeImgUrl)
                    const qrDoc = {
                        QrcodeImg: qrcodeImgUrl,
                        expiredDateTime: enrollmentToken.data.expirationTimestamp
                    };

                } else {
                    // If no policies were found, send a not found response
                    console.log('No policies found for the given email and policy name.');
                    await res.redirect('/provision-Template');
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Update Error", error)
            }
            // expiredDateTime: enrollmentToken.data.expirationTimestamp
            await res.redirect('/provision-Template');

        
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating enrollment token:', error.message);
    }
};

References : - https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb#scrollTo=TTSgnpC9EScx


I am having a similar problem and it turns out that the API is getting shut down. https://support.google.com/docs/thread/251700701

Thank you for your helpful suggestion, @AlexanderHolland. I really appreciated it. I followed your advice and tried creating a QR code. Unfortunately, I was unable to provision my device using it. However, I was able to provision my device successfully by using the image-chart located at https://documentation.image-charts.com/qr-codes/#overview. Once again, I would like to express my gratitude for your kind assistance.

The https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr api had been deprecated for years, and has now finally been taken down. You'll need to find a different way to generate a QR code. I'd advise you to use one of the many qr code generating libraries available instead of relying on an api because:

Using someone else's server to generate QR codes poses a security risk
Making a QR code is very simple when you use a library.

You can consider using https://github.com/nayuki/QR-Code-generator.
